# BeautifulSoup: Extracting text from nested tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

Long time lurker, first time poster. I spent some time looking over related questions but I still couldn't seem to figure this out. I think it's easy enough but please forgive me, I'm still a bit of a BeautifulSoup/python n00b.

I have a text file of URLs I parsed from a previous webscraping exercise that I'd like to search through and extract the text contents of a list item (`<li>`) based on a given keyword. I want to save a csv file of the URL as one column and the corresponding contents from the list item in the second column. In this case, it's albums that I'd like to create a table of by who mastered the album, produced the album, etc.

Given a snippet of html:
from https://www.discogs.com/release/7896531-The-Rolling-Stones-Some-Girls

```
...
<li>
<span class="entity_1XpR8">Recorded By</span>
" – " 
<a href="/label/394786-EMI-Studios-Paris" hreflang="en" class="link_1ctor">EMI Studios, Paris</a>
</li>

<li>
<span class="entity_1XpR8">Mastered At</span>
 " – " 
<a href="/label/264060-Sterling-Sound" hreflang="en" class="link_1ctor">Sterling Sound</a>
</li>


etc etc etc

...
```

My code so far is something like:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

results = []
kw = "Mastered At"

with open("urls.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        url = line.rstrip()
        source = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
        x = soup.find_all('span', string='Mastered At')
        results.append((url, x))

print(results)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv('mylist1.csv')
```

With some modifications based on comments below, still having issues:
As you can see I'm trying to do this within a for loop for each link in a list.

The URL list is a simple text file with separate lines for each. Since I'm scraping only one website the sources, class names, and etc should be the same, but the dish will change from page to page.

ex URL list:

```
https://www.discogs.com/release/7896531-The-Rolling-Stones-Some-Girls
https://www.discogs.com/release/3872976-Pink-Floyd-The-Wall
... etc etc etc
```

updated code snippet:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

results = []

with open("urls.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        url = line.rstrip()
        print(url)
        source = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
        for x in [x for x in soup.select('li') if x.select_one('span.spClass').text.strip() == 'Mastered At']:
            results.append((x.select_one('a.linkClass').get('href'), x.select_one('a.linkClass').text.strip(),
                            x.select_one('span.spClass').text.strip()))

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Url', 'Mastered At', 'Studio'])

print(df)
df.to_csv('studios.csv')
```

I'm hoping the output in this case is Col 1: (url from txt file); Col 2: "Mastered At — Sterling Sound" (or just "Sterling Sound"), but for each page in the list because these items vary from page to page. I will change the keyword to extract different list items accordingly. In the end I'd like one big spreadsheet with the full list or the url and corresponding item side by side something like below:

example:
album url  | Sterling Sound 
album url  | Abbey Road
album url  | Abbey Road
album url  | Sterling Sound
album url  | Real World Studios
album url  | EMI Studios, Paris
album url  | Sterling Sound

etc etc etc

Thanks for your help!
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Beautiful Soup` library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is best suited for this task.

You can use the following code to extract data:

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# urls.html would be better
with open("urls.txt") as file:
    src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

for first, second in zip(soup.select("li span"), soup.select("li a")):
    print(first)
    print(second)
```

To find the desired selector, you can use the [`select()` `bs4` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). This method accepts a selector to search for and returns a `list` of all matched HTML elements.

In this case, I use the [`zip()` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), which allows you to go through two structures at once in one cycle.

Then you can use the data for your tasks.

Comment: Hi Artur, Thanks for your reply. I tried this method but for some reason lxml is either not installed or not recognized. I tried sudo pip install lxml running Pycharm 2021.3.3 and Python 3.9

Comment: Then you can write `html.parser` instead of `lxml`

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')`

Comment: You can learn more about the difference between `html.parser` and `lxml` by reading the paragraph in `BeautifulSoup` documentation called [Differences between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup can use different parsers for html. If you have issues with `lxml` you can try others, like `html.parser`. You can try the following code, it will create a dataframe from your data, which can then be further saved to csv or other formats:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = '''
<li>
<span class = "spClass">Breakfast</span> " — "
<a href="/examplepage/Pancakes" class="linkClass">Pancakes</a>
</li>

<li>
<span class = "spClass">Lunch</span> " — "
<a href="/examplepage/Sandwiches" class="linkClass">Sandwiches</a>
</li>

<li>
<span class = "spClass">Dinner</span> " — "
<a href="/examplepage/Stew" class="linkClass">Stew</a>
</li>

'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
df_list = []
for x in soup.select('li'):
    df_list.append((x.select_one('a.linkClass').get('href'), x.select_one('a.linkClass').text.strip(), x.select_one('span.spClass').text.strip()))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=['Url', 'Food', 'Type'])
print(df) ## you can save the dataframe as csv like so: df.to_csv('foods.csv')
```

Result:

```
Url Food    Type
0   /examplepage/Pancakes   Pancakes    Breakfast
1   /examplepage/Sandwiches Sandwiches  Lunch
2   /examplepage/Stew   Stew    Dinner
```

EDIT: If you only want to extract specific `li` tags, as per your comment, you can do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
df_list = []
for x in [x for x in soup.select('li') if x.select_one('span.spClass').text.strip() == 'Dinner']:
    df_list.append((x.select_one('a.linkClass').get('href'), x.select_one('a.linkClass').text.strip(), x.select_one('span.spClass').text.strip()))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=['Url', 'Food', 'Type'])
```

And this will return:

```
Url Food    Type
0   /examplepage/Stew   Stew    Dinner
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I'm used to seeing html.parser so this looks more familiar. What do you recommend I just wanted to extract ONE of these `<li>` tags like "Dinner", but none of the rest? End goal is I'd like a list of just one meal type and corresponding dish for each URL in the list for in this particular example. Since each `<li>` in this example doesn't have an individual name identifier I'm having trouble finding out how to search only for the given term and pulling the text from that list item. Thanks again!

Comment: Edited my response to show you how you can filter the tags extracted.

Comment: Hi there, thanks again for your reply. I implemented your suggestions but I'm still having issues. I edited my original comment with your code placed in the for loop that's iterating through the link list. I'm getting an error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' on the first line of the for loop you suggested when I run the snippet I added to my comment. Thank you.

Comment: How does your urls.txt look like?

Comment: It's just a text file with multiple lines .... www.url1.com/restaurantName1/ ... www.url2.com/restaurantName2/

Comment: I edited my original post with more context for the url list. Thanks again! I appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to post the actual urls, so whoever is willing to help you can actually scrape that content, look at it and process it as per your request.

Comment: You're right, fair enough. I updated the main post with the actual code and full context. Basically I'm scraping a list of records on discogs.com to see who mastered, produced the records, and etc. Hopefully it makes sense when you see the full post and example source code. Let me know if you have other questions. Thanks for your patience/help!!! :))